# How to add analyzer settings in ElasticSearch?

Tags: java, indexing, elasticsearch, lucene, analyzer

I am using ElasticSearch 1.5.2 and I wish to have the following settings :

```
"settings": {
"analysis": {
    "filter": {
        "filter_shingle": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "max_shingle_size": 2,
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "output_unigrams": false
        },
        "filter_stemmer": {
            "type": "porter_stem",
            "language": "English"
        }
    },
    "tokenizer": {
        "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
            "type": "nGram",
            "min_gram": 1,
            "max_gram": 1
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "ShingleAnalyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer",
            "filter": [
                "standard",
                "lowercase",
                "filter_stemmer",
                "filter_shingle"
            ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Where should I add them? I mean before index creation or after?

By searching online I found some method like

```
client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("temp_index").setSettings(ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().loadFromSource((jsonBuilder()
    .startObject()
       .startObject("analysis")
          .startObject("analyzer")......and so on)
```

But I am having 2 issues,

1. I get a compile error : The method loadFromSource in the type ImmutableSettings.builder is not applicable for the arguments XContentBuilder
2. Also, I don't know how to convert my settings to this format. And where is the documentation to get to know about all these methods?
   I tried reading the official ElasticSearch JAVA API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html but I was unable to find anything about setting up analyzers.
   All the related content I find is only in the form of REST APIs and not in Java API.

Comment: So, do you want to add setting with java api? Or Direct using REST ?

Comment: I want to add using java api.

Comment: If you could provide a link for java api documentation for analyzers, it would be very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XContentBuilder` have specific syntax , can be used to create a json object.

You can follow https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index_.html#helpers to convert your string to `XContentBuilder` format.

If you have same string loaded in application. 
You simply can do.

```
    client.admin().indices()
.prepareCreate("index_name").setSettings("{setting _ json _ string }").get()
```

Will simply work.

If you want to know how the json will look like in XContentBuilder, then here it is,

```
XContentBuilder settingsBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
        .startObject()
            .startObject("analysis")
                .startObject("filter")
                    .startObject("filter_shingle")
                        .field("type","shingle")
                        .field("max_shingle_size",2)
                        .field("min_shingle_size",2)
                        .field("output_unigrams",false)
                    .endObject()
                    .startObject("filter_stemmer")
                        .field("type","porter_stem")
                        .field("language","English")
                    .endObject()
                .endObject()
                .startObject("tokenizer")
                    .startObject("my_ngram_tokenizer")
                        .field("type","nGram")
                        .field("min_gram",1)
                        .field("max_gram",1)
                    .endObject()
                .endObject()
                .startObject("analyzer")
                    .startObject("ShingleAnalyzer")
                        .field("tokenizer","my_ngram_tokenizer")
                        .array("filter","standard","lowercase","filter_stemmer","filter_shingle")
                    .endObject()
                .endObject()
            .endObject()
        .endObject()

client.admin().indices()
.prepareCreate("index_name").setSettings(settingsBuilder).get()
```

Comment: Can you please provide the source from where you got this `client.admin().indices()
.prepareCreate("index_name").setSettings("{setting _ json _ string }").get()` ?

Comment: source ? If you are asking me about documentation, then I am looking at elasticsearch code.

Comment: as in the original elasticsearch source code? No documentation available for it??

Comment: I am sorry, I don't think there is proper documentation of java api, If you look at elasticsearch client , org.elasticsearch.client.Client class, then you can find out what methods are available.